# How to add custom query to comment entity

Tags: 8, comments

I have comment thread field attached into a node. I would like to have a search function by keyword.

I used `hook_query_TAG_alter()` to add database condition according to my needs.

Here's my current code:-

```
if ($query->getMetaData('base_table') == 'comment') {
  $query->leftJoin('comment__comment_body', 'ccb', 'c.cid = ccb.entity_id');

  $or = db_or();
  $or->condition('ccb.comment_body_value', "%$keyword%", 'LIKE');
  $query->condition($or);
}
```

The above code is working, but I also would like to get the parent comment to be able to determine where the comment results coming from.

I'm trying to add the `comment_field_data` table where the thread is stored. However, I'm not sure on how to get the parent comment according to the thread name in the results or if it's possible that way.

Here's a sample comment with replies:-

```
Comment Parent with no replies
Comment Parent with replies
  - This is a test reply
  - This is a test comment
  - This is a test
```

If I searched on a keyword "reply", then the result should be like below:-

```
Comment Parent with replies
  - This is a test reply
```

Should I just create a custom field widget to have full control with the query?

Any recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thanks!